# How can I issue a certificate from a CA keypair and CSR?

Tags: openssl, certificate

Now I have these files:

CA Keypair (RSA 4096):

`ca.pem`, `ca-key.pem`

Certificate Keypair (ECC 384):

`server.csr`, `server-key.pem`

How can I issue the server certificate "server.pem"?

The certificate chain should look like this:

> Example CA
>
> example.com

Answer (score 1):

`openssl x509` will sign the certificate for you:

```
openssl x509 -req -set_serial 1234 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out server.pem
```

However, it's very unlikely that it will produce exactly what you're expecting.  Have a read of the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/x509.html) for all the details.  For example, you may want to add specific extensions to the certificate, such as a SAN.  In such cases, you need to create a file containing the extension, as follows:

```
[ san_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = example.com
```

The save it (e.g. as `san.cnf`).  Finally, tell OpenSSL about it with the `-extfile` and the `-extensions` options:

```
openssl x509 -req -set_serial 1234 -ext file san.cnf -extensions san_ext -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out server.pem
```

Comment: Yes, the certificate is now issued, but missing SAN. How to add it, then?